# how to increment field value each time selenium test is run?

Tags: selenium

is there any simple way to increment for example field value by +1 every time Selenium test is run through Selenium IDE?

```
Command: Type 
Target: some kind of id
Value: number+1
```

**EDIT 1** :thanks for a reply krosenvold. i got your idea and this is a simplified version of what i got so far:

```
...     
store | 10 | x
storeEval | storedVars['x'] = ${x}+1 | 
...
```

variable's x value does realy get incremented, but how would you save that value between distinct test runs? is it even possible?

should i get $x value every time the test is run and at the end of it assign $x value to some dummy element on testing page, so i could retrieve that previously incremented value the next time test is run?

Answer (score 6):

**Correct Answer**

store | 10 | i

store | javascript{storedVars.i++;} | i

echo  | ${i}

Comment: This works for me only with the plus signs in front, like so: javascript{++storedVars.i;}

Answer (score 4):

This is solution for your problem

```
store | 10 | i
store | javascript{storedVars.i++;} 
echo  | ${i}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
store          | 0                                | iterator
echo           | ${iterator}                      |
execute script | return parseInt(${iterator}) + 1 | iterator
echo           | ${iterator}                      |
```

As result will be:

```
0
1
```

Comment: increment field value *each time* selenium test is run

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval`;

```
eval($('elementId').value = $('elementId').value +1);
```

The exact syntax I'm showing implies prototype on the client;

`document.getElementById('elementId').value` should also do the trick in a `standard DOM` environment.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
storeEval | storedVars['nextRow'] = ${nextRow}+1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use localStorage:

```
execute script | localStorage.setItem('i', parseInt((localStorage.getItem('i')) || 1)+1)

execute script | return localStorage.getItem('i') | i

echo           | ${i}
```