# Selenium IDE decrement value of var

Tags: selenium-ide, decrement

Hi I'm trying to do a simple decrement in Selenium but it isn't returning the subtraction, instead of it is returning a string. Follow my code:

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>contador</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>${contador}--</td>
    <td>contador</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${contador}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Expected: 1

But get: 2--

Answer (score 0):

I've found! Someone put an example in "[how to increment field value each time selenium test is run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789114/how-to-increment-field-value-each-time-selenium-test-is-run)"

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>contador</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>storeEval</td>
    <td>storedVars['contador'] = ${contador}-1</td>
    <td>contador</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${contador}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
```

Now the result is 1!!!