# How to increment a text field by 1 in selenium?

Tags: selenium-ide

I have a question about [how to increment field value each time selenium test is run?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/789114/how-to-increment-field-value-each-time-selenium-test-is-run/38125979#38125979).

I have read the answers but am unclear at what point should the echo command should be placed. I have a repeating test where I am entering the number 1 into a text field. And every time the test runs I would like that to increment by one.

I'm also assuming I can put the two "store" commands anywhere near the top of the test.

Also if I go with the javascript{storedVars.i++;} example, would I put the variable i in the text field instead of the number 1?

I'm a relative newb so feel free to talk to me like a 4 year old.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer!  Don't know all the etiquette here yet but I need to give props to this website that helped me figure it out.

http://traceyqa.blogspot.com/2011/02/incremental-variables-in-selenium_23.html